# Ethereum (Java) API

Tags: etherscan

has anyone a good suggestion for a well-documented Ethereum API that is not limited by requests and allows to gather all information about token (transfers)?

Basically an api that provides information such as Etherscan (not sutiable since it limits the requests - I'd need about 100+ requests per minute) does.

Ideally I would like to gather the information "directly" from ht Ethereum chain and not being dependent on a third-party like Etherscan.

Comment: Hi there. Etherscan limits to 5 requests per second - is that not enough? With regards to not relying on a third party, in that case you'd probably want to run your own archive/full node, so you'd need to provide your own hardware and bandwidth to do so.

Comment: Moreover, if you want to gather data without depending on a third party, you have to run your own node. anything else requires you depend on whoever is offering the API/node proxy

Comment: @RichardHorrocks Thanks! 5 requests per second might work for the beginning but as soon as I want to scale the app it won't be sufficient. Is there a good tutorial for setting up a full node for that purpose?

Answer (score 0):

To set up a full node, if you want to avoid getting frustrated again and again, set up your node on Ubuntu 16.04, ram should be preferably 8 GB atleast and a good Internet connection .

- Go to geth downloads and download an installer for your system and then run

  - If your installation is successful, you'll see geth version details on the terminal when you type geth version.
  - After that simply run geth - - cache=your value whatever you want to give according to your ram, in the directory where you want the blockchain data to be placed. The default syncmode for geth is fast.
  - If you want to stop the synchronization at any time, press Ctrl + C.
  - If you want to shift the data to another system simple copy the whole folder to your usb or hard disk. And when you have transferred the data on the other system simply run geth - - datadir "path of ethereum" - - cache=whatever you wanna give.
  - To check synchronization progress open another terminal and type geth attach ipc:the url value you see once block synchronization has started in the previous. terminal.

Regarding your other question you might want to check out web3j and infura apis.